# ASP.NET MVC: How to hide first column in the Webgrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

i use this code to hide a column in webgrid.

```
grid.Column(null, null, format: @<input type="hidden" name="IDHidden" value="@item.ID" />),
```

now my grid UI look like below one which is not right. enter image description here
[image]

the above code does help me to hide my first column. i search google and got a css which promise to hide webgrid column. so i used this css

```
.webgrid-table td:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(1){
            display:none
        }
```

the above css hide my first column but my pager also become invisible which was not my intention.

i am looking for a css which will hide first column of webgrid but will not hide pager if webgrid has any. looking for help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
hideColumn = function (column) {
    $('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td,th').eq(column).hide();
    });
};
hideColumn(0);
```

Please put this code inside: `$(document).ready(function (){});`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the 2nd column, for instance:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#yourGridId th:nth-child(2)").hide();
  $("#yourGridId td:nth-child(2)").hide();
  }
```

Hides the col including the header.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the row in webgrid using mvc5

your view should have below section -

```
 var grid = new WebGrid(
                    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(data);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
        fillEmptyRows: false,
         tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column("Container_No", "Container No", canSort: false),
          grid.Column("SizeText", "SizeList", canSort: false),
           grid.Column("ContainerText", "Container Type", canSort: false),
            grid.Column("CargoText", "Cargo Type", canSort: false),
           grid.Column(header: "Action", canSort: false, style: "col-lg-2",
            format: @<text>              
     @Html.Raw("<a href='#' id='" + item.Container_No + "' onclick='goDelete(id);'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span></a>")
```

please include below function in your script --

```
function goDelete(data) {
     $(".page-loader-wrapper").show();`enter code here`
    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this Container Entry?")) {          
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
                data: '{Container_No: ' + data + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (response) {                        
                    $("#" + data).parents("tr").remove();
                    $(".page-loader-wrapper").hide();

                   alert(data + "Container removed successfully !!");                                             
                }
            });
        }
    }
```